# Constructor default non optional parameters initializes objects?

Tags: php, laravel

I have trouble understanding the type hinting and initializing of arguments in the constructor.
I stumbled across this code:

```
class TabController {
    protected $post;
    protected $user;
    public function __construct(Post $post, User $user)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

I thought that arguments wasn't optional if it wasn't set up like this:

```
public function __construct(Post $post=NULL, User $user=NULL)
```

It seems both these examples initializes an empty object (not NULL).

If I try the first example in a normal function it fails if I dont supply the arguments.

Comment: How do you create the instance?

Comment: The type-hinting will surely not create objects. And using `null` for defaults will just set the parameter to `null` if not supplied.

Comment: @Yoshi, yeah that's what I thought. Maybe I've missed something in the instance creation like Chumkiu suggests. The actual code is from https://github.com/andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site/blob/master/app/controllers/admin/AdminBlogsController.php , I will try to dig a little in the underlying code (unless type hinting in constructors are fundamentally different wich I doubt, thus this question).

Comment: `Post $post` means an object of type `Post` must be supplied. `Post $post = null` means that the parameter is optional and can be an object of type `Post` *or `null`/nothing*. Not sure what your question is beyond this.

Comment: @deceze If I just initialize the class with Post $post, not supplying an argument (that I know of), it still initializes an empty Post object. I suspect the underlying framework might be injecting stuff.

Comment: We'd need more actual code to say anything about this.

Comment: `class Foo{ public function __construct(StdClass $x) {} } $foo = new Foo;` complains about not passing a StdClass instance as paramter to the constructor.

Comment: @deceze Yes, that's why I linked to it all in my first comment. The codebase is pretty big though so it might be pointless. Thinkiong of contacting the author of the class, may be simpler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out the Laravel framework makes use of the PHP's Reflection facilities for automatic resolution.. Case closed. Thanks for trying to help out!

[Laravel docs about Automatic Resolution](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#automatic-resolution)

Answer (score 2):

First, type hinting.
It is intended for verification input data.
For example:

```
class User {
    protected $city;
    public function __construct(City $city) {
        $this->city = $city;
    }
}
class City {}
class Country {}
$city = new City(); $user = new User($city); //all ok
$country = new Country(); $user = new User($country); //throw a catchable fatal error
```

Second, initializing an empty object.
This is done as follows:

```
class User {
    protected $city;
    public function __construct(City $city = null) {
        if (empty($city)) { $city = new City(); }
        $this->city = $city;
    }
}
```